# Multiple instances of a class with constant variables use same memory for constants?

Tags: c++, optimization, memory, static, constants

If I have a class that defines multiple constant variables like so...

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass() : SOME_CONSTANT(20), ANOTHER_CONSTANT(45), ANOTHER_CONSTANT2(25), ANOTHER_CONSTANT2(93) { }

private:
    const int SOME_CONSTANT;
    const int ANOTHER_CONSTANT;
    const int ANOTHER_CONSTANT2;
    const int ANOTHER_CONSTANT3;
```

Will multiple instances of this class be optimized to point to the same memory for the constants? or can I save memory by making each constant static?

Comment: If the constants are going to be the same for all classes you should make them static by design. Other than this I do not think that the compiler will offer this optimization - of course this depends on your compiler..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they are not static, then no, they will not be optimized out. Each instance will have space for all the constants. (In fact, I don't think the compiler is even allowed to combine them in any way.)

If you do declare them static, they are in global memory and not in each instance. So yes, it will use less memory.

EDIT:

If you want to make them static constants, it should be done like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    public:
        SomeClass(){ }

    private:
        static const int SOME_CONSTANT;
        static const int ANOTHER_CONSTANT;
        static const int ANOTHER_CONSTANT2;
        static const int ANOTHER_CONSTANT3;

};

const int SomeClass::SOME_CONSTANT     = 20;
const int SomeClass::ANOTHER_CONSTANT  = 45;
const int SomeClass::ANOTHER_CONSTANT2 = 25;
const int SomeClass::ANOTHER_CONSTANT3 = 93;
```

Comment: You're correct that the compiler may not optimize them away, at least for standard-layout types.

Comment: This actually depends on the compiler. If I'm not wrong `gcc` or `g++` has problems with this and counts the constants as defined twice. If I'm wrong, than VS gives this as error, I don't remember and I can't test now. As we know, there's an exception for static integral types in the ISO standard.

Comment: I tested this in VS before I made the edit and it works. They are *declared* inside the class, but *defined* outside.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference and I'll edit my question later today and inform you what I mean :)

Answer (score 3):

How about an enumeration instead?

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass() { }

private:
    enum {
        SOME_CONSTANT = 20,
        ANOTHER_CONSTANT = 45,
        ANOTHER_CONSTANT2 = 25,
        ANOTHER_CONSTANT3 = 93
    };
};
```

An enumeration guarantees that the constants won't take up any memory at all.

Comment: Yes, see my edit. Enumerations are entirely free memory-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Declared this way, all instances of this class will have its own copies. To avoid this and save memory, declare them as `static`.

Note: don't forget to define them outside the class. As these are `int`s, you may avoid defining them outside the class, this actually depends more on the compiler, than the standard (yes, I know how ridiculous this soudns). I can't test it now, but I remember, that `gcc` and `VS` have different behaviors about this.

So, you may need to do this:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass()
    { }

private:
    static const int SOME_CONSTANT;
    static const int ANOTHER_CONSTANT;
    static const int ANOTHER_CONSTANT2;
    static const int ANOTHER_CONSTANT3;

const int SomeClass::SOME_CONSTANT = 20;
//.. the same for the others.
```

***EDIT*** I'll find this part of the standard (the exception for integral types) and post it here + tests on both compilers later today :) )

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make those constants static - simply because your constructor initialses them!

```
SomeClass() : SOME_CONSTANT(20), ANOTHER_CONSTANT(45), ANOTHER_CONSTANT2(25), ANOTHER_CONSTANT2(93) { }
```

Remove those initialisers i.e.

```
SomeClass{};
static const int SOME_CONSTANT = 20;
```

Then you will have just one `int` for the class.

Comment: But @replicant may remove the initializer list. I don't think it's a good ide to make them global, if only objects from this class will use them.

Answer (score -1):

You can try checking the sizeof() of an instance of the class. I don't think they'll be optimized out. Using const static variables for this purpose will probably be the right thing to do, especially if they are all integers, in which case you can initialize them at the definition and get compile time constants without worrying about static objects initialization order.

```
class SomeClass
{
private:
    const static int SOME_CONSTANT     = 20;
    const static int ANOTHER_CONSTANT  = 45;
    const static int ANOTHER_CONSTANT2 = 25;
    const static int ANOTHER_CONSTANT3 = 93;
};
```